# Height of the outside div is not changing according to inside divs and elements

Tags: css

I have a div (maincontent) which is inside another div (container). These divs are located in aspx page, and I have many asp.net controls inside the insider div (maincontent). But it is so interesting that the site looks like this;

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/omahx.jpg

The white part (maincontent) should be resized according to the elemnts inside. But it's height is shown as 0px.

Here is the css of maincontent and container;

```
#container
{
background: #FFF;
width: 1000px;
height:auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
border-right: 2px solid #B0AA94;
border-left: 2px solid #B0AA94;
border-bottom: 2px solid #B0AA94;
border-radius: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
}

#maincontent
{
height: auto;
font-family: Trebuchet MS;
font-size: 10px;
color: Black;
margin-left: 30px;
margin-top: 40px;
}
```

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You likely have a lot of floated elements within those containers. You'll need to clear them. You can clear floated elements by setting their container's overflow property to "auto" or "hidden".

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JyAMb/

Comment: so is there any way to fix this "with" floated elements,or a better way to float elements ?

Comment: @MustafaTok Yes, set 'overflow:hidden' or 'overflow:auto' to the container. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/JyAMb/

Answer (score 2):

Floating a div takes it out of the normal flow of elements. Add `<div style="clear:both">` after your floating divs to clear them.